# sorting on List<string> with middle 2 character

Tags: c#, sorting

I like to sort a list with middle 2 character. for example: The list contains following:

```
body1text
body2text
body11text
body3text
body12text
body13text
```

if I apply list.OrderBy(r => r.body), it will sort as follows:

```
body1text
body11text
body12text
body13text
body2text
body3text
```

But I need the following result:

```
body1text
body2text
body3text
body11text
body12text
body13text
```

is there any easy way to sort with middle 2 digit character?

Regards
Shuvra

Comment: What is the middle 2 characters of `abc`? `abcd`? `abcde`?

Comment: 2 characters that become 3 after 99 and 4 after 999 etc..

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that your numbers are compared as strings, so `string.Compare("11", "2")` will return `-1` meaning that "11" is less than "2". Assuming that your string is always in format "body" + n numbers + "text" you can match numbers with regex and parse an integer from result:

```
new[] 
{
    "body1text"
    ,"body2text"
    ,"body3text"
    ,"body11text"
    ,"body12text"
    ,"body13text"
}
.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s,@"\d+").Value))
```